# не могу преобразовать этот код "%2С"

Tags: http

`%3A` - это `:`, `%2F` - это `/`. А `%2С` - это что?

Comment: `,` - для декодирования используй [decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)

Comment: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: `,`, разве нет?. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Comment: @andy Вы бы хоть почитали комментарии выше

Comment: укажите какой язык используете

Comment: @tutankhamun ох уж эти ответы в комментариях...

Answer (score 1):

`%2С` - это `,`

[таблица ASCII Encoding на сайте w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

Дополнительно можно почитать про [URL-кодирование](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#.D0.9A.D0.BE.D0.B4.D0.B8.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_URL)